# Переадресация по UTM

Tags: php, redirect

Нашел код, но он работает не корректно.
Суть заключается в том что получаем данные с `URL` одной `UTM` метки, далее по ней делаем условие, если не совпадает то редерикт с пробросом `UTM` далее.
Слов может быть несколько.
На данный момент почти все работает, но не правильно.

Php:

```
$utm = $_REQUEST['utm_term'];
$ipmasks = array( '{keyword}', ); 
$pattern = join('|', array_map('preg_quote', $ipmasks)); 
$pattern = str_replace('\*', '\d+', $pattern); 

if(preg_match('#^('.$pattern.')#', $utm, $_GET['utm_term']) == 0)  
 { 
    header("Location: http://test.com/index.php?".$_REQUEST['QUERY_STRING']);
 }
```

Comment: что означает *пости все* и как неправильно?

Comment: Если условия utm_term={keyword} то страница постоянно обновляется.

Comment: В рабочем варианте необходимо что бы была проверка, если условия не равно, то редирикт, если равно то оставить на этой странице

Comment: Сам решил, добавил в конце exit;

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

еще такой нашел код

```
$map = array(
    'adwords'  => 'adwords',
    'yadirect' => 'direct',
);

if( $_GET['utm_source'] AND $map[ $_GET['utm_source'] ] )
{
    $url = 'http://'.$map[ $_GET['utm_source'] ].'.site.ru'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: '.$url, false, 301);
    exit();
}
```